# can't install and get error while installing parcel by npm install -D parcel

Tags: reactjs, parcel

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/parcel - Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'parcel@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-15T20_56_26_105Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\name\Desktop\React>

npm install -D parcel

after that i tried

npm install --save-dev https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel
then it gives me

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force -
-cache=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --
no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/@babel%2fcore - Not Found
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404  '@babel/core@7.21.4' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check if npm registry is set correctly.

```
npm config get registry
```

This will show you the registry, if its not set to https://registry.npmjs.org/, set it by running

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If it still does not work, try updating you npm and node versions and restart the terminal.